# Part of SVG image is disappearing when resizing

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a Vue project where I used svg icons as image in my navigation. When I resize my icons some parts of the icons are disappearing and etc.

[image: img]

```
<div class="navigation nav-item">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="../assets/navicons/home-blue.svg" alt />
            <router-link :to="'/'">Главная</router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="../assets/navicons/list-blue.svg" alt />
            <router-link :to="'/materials'">Учебный материал</router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="../assets/navicons/tests-blue.svg" alt />
            <router-link :to="'/test'">Тесты</router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="../assets/navicons/Book.svg" alt />
            <router-link :to="'/portfolio'">Портфолио</router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="../assets/navicons/Shop.svg" alt />
            <router-link :to="'/library'">Библиотека</router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: There is an interesting article here: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ . I would also check the differences between the svg files you have there, as the first few do not change. Maybe it's a problem of the specific svg that is shown in the gif.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would be really beneficial here. Could you extract just computed style and structure of the third `li`, attach source of `tests-blue.svg` and tell versions of browsers exhibiting this behaviour?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the svg code for one of your images

Comment: Thank you guys. I checked my svg code and just added with and height and that's it. It's worked!